# Need to while loop and display contents in the subfield of a group field given by ACF

Tags: loop, advanced-custom-fields

I need to display out the content inside the while loop and by taking the values that i have given in sub-field a group field created in ACF.

- field group name:career_details
- field group label:career details
- field type:group
- rule:page-template = career-page(my required page)
- rule:page-template = career-page(my required page)
- sub field name:job_position,job_location,job_description
- sub fieled label:job position,job location,job description

theses are the details of field respectevely.

then i have added contents to the all sub fields.
when i try to run the following code ,there is no any output.
the contents inside the loop is disappeared.

```
<section class="container" >


<?php if( have_rows('career_details') ): //parent group field
while( have_rows('career_details') ): the_row(); 
?>


<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
<div class="col-md-3 no-padd">
<a class="btn btn-success btn-lg green-buttn" href=""><h3 class="h3 
text-buttn text-uppercase"><?php the_sub_field('job_location');  ?> 
</h3></a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 no-padd">
<a class="btn btn-danger btn-lg red-buttn" href=""><h3 class="h3 text- 
buttn text-uppercase"><?php the_sub_field('job_position');  ?></h3></a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 no-padd d-block">
<div class="click-upload float-right"><a href=""><img class="cv-img" 
src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/cv-upload.jpg" 
alt=""></a></div>

<div class="click-upload float-right"><a href=""><p class="cv- 
text">Click here to <br> upload your cv</p></a></div>
<hr class="hr-dark">
</div>

</div>
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-start">
<h3 class="h3 small-head">Details of this position</h3>
<p class="h5 small-para">
<?php  the_sub_field('job_description') ; ?>
</p>


</div>
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-start bl-btn">
<a class="btn btn-primary blue-btn" href="">
<p class=" text-uppercase name-btn">apply now</p>
</a>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php  endif; ?>


</div>

</section>
```

Can any one help me to find out

Comment: Are you inside the main Loop of this template - the `if(have_posts() ...` part? If so, have you set your custom field to be assigned to a specific Post/Page, or are these fields edited in an options page? If they're edited in an options page, you have to add an additional parameter to all of your `the_field()`, `the_sub_field()` calls. And if you're not inside the main Loop, you need to include the post ID in your calls to them, so ACF knows which Post/Page to pull them from.

Comment: thank you Elaine,as you said ,i was not inside of mail loop.now it is working correctly.you pointed out in the right time